# With editor status changes to Submitted to Journal After 5 weeks

Tags: peer-review, editors, elsevier

May I please ask what does this mean. I submitted a manuscript to an Elsevier journal, for 5 weeks it had "with editor" status, now it has changed to "Submitted to Journal". What does this mean?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the typical workflow of a journal look like?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/55665/what-does-the-typical-workflow-of-a-journal-look-like)

Answer (score 1):

Elsevier has a page where they explain the submission status [1]. I would assume that "submitted to journal" is equivalent to the status "with journal" on that page. My guess would be that this means that the editor handling your manuscript is being changed. More detailed information if and why this is happening can probably only come from the journal itself, so you would have to contact them directly.

[1] [https://service.elsevier.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/12237/supporthub/publishing/~/what-does-the-status-of-my-submission-mean-in-evise%3F/](https://service.elsevier.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/12237/supporthub/publishing/%7E/what-does-the-status-of-my-submission-mean-in-evise%3F/)

Comment: This would probably be a nice addition to the canonical answer mentioned in the comments.